# Simulink - Gazebo CoSimulation setup doubts

Tags: ros, gazebo, matlab, gazebo-plugin, rosmatlab

I am building a model (of a cable) and a controller in simulink to actuate the end points of the cable in simulink. Since matlab is a numerical simulator and it lacks physics based interactions with the environment, I am thinking to use Gazebo for it (water interactions). I want to close the loop and do realtime co-simulation.

I saw matlab documentation for it - https://nl.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/perform-co-simulation-between-simulink-and-gazebo.html

I do not understand the step to perform - packageGazeboPlugin
Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "the step to perform - packageGazeboPlugin"?

This is a function in Robotics System Toolbox (RST), if you have this toolbox installed, you can run this command directly in MATLAB Command Window:

```
>> packageGazeboPlugin
```

Please feel free to reach out to [MathWorks Technical Support](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html) team if you need further assistant.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused with the step. Reaching out to the technical support helped me :)